# Join multiple Tables in MS Access/SQLQuery with conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I'm trying to join 3 tables, A, B and C on Field "Policy". Tables B and C also have a field called "Value".
The Policy Field in A only stores the first 4 digits of each policy whereas B and C stores the full 7 digits.

What I'm trying to do is, sum the Values of each match between A and B, then look up each match between A and B in C; if the policy exists in C, sum Values in C; if the policy does not exist in C, return 0. Finally, take the difference between Values summed from B and Values summed from C, floored at zero.

Sorry I know it sounds a bit confusing. I made some simple tables to illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish here. "..." simply means there are tons of other entries not displayed in each table. In the desired table, the intermediate columns (Values from B, Values from C and Calculation) are not required and are simply for illustration. All I care about is the "Final" number.

**[Illustration]**

[image]

Now, what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT 
   Sum(IIf([B]![Value]>[C]![Value],[B]![Value]-[C]![Value],0)) AS [Final]
   FROM [C], [B], [A]
   WHERE (((Left([C].[Policy],4))=[A].[Policy]) AND ((Left([B].[Policy],4))=[A].[Policy]));
```

(Not so) Obviously, the problems with this is that it inner joins all A, B and C, and does not return zero for what's in A and B but not in C, as I desired. Where should I change?

Comment: Hi Tim! Thanks for your reply. I’m sorry I know it’s a bit confusing. That’s why I attached a picture of tables A, B, C and desired results. Were you able to see it?

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple and just join `A` to two subqueries, one each for the `B` and `C` tables:

```
SELECT
    a.Policy,
    Nz(b.b_value, 0) AS b_value,
    Nz(c.c_value, 0) AS c_value,
    Nz(b.b_value, 0) - Nz(c.c_value, 0) AS final
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT LEFT(Policy, 4) AS Policy, SUM(Value) AS b_value
    FROM tableB
    GROUP BY LEFT(Policy, 4)
) b
    ON a.Policy = b.Policy
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT LEFT(Policy, 4) AS Policy, SUM(Value) AS c_value
    FROM tableC
    GROUP BY LEFT(Policy, 4)
) b
    ON a.Policy = c.Policy;
```

Note that you may want to also handle the possibility that a policy in `A` does not match to anything in either `B` or `C`.  The `Nz()` function would be useful for that.

Comment: I do want to handle the possibility that policies in A do not match anything in B or C, and in these cases, I would like to return 0's in the column for values. Would the Nz() do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that:

```
WITH
B1 AS (SELECT LEFT(POLICY,4) AS POLICY,Value AS BValue,0 AS CValue)
,C1 AS (SELECT LEFT(POLICY,4) AS POLICY,0 AS BValue,Value AS CValue)
,D AS (
    SELECT
        A.POLYCY
        ,SUM(isNULL(B1.BValue,0)+isNULL(C2.BValue,0)) AS BValues
        ,SUM(isNULL(B1.CValue,0)+isNULL(C1.CValue,0)) AS CValues
    FROM A
        LEFT JOIN B1 ON B1.POLICY=A.POLICY
        LEFT JOIN C1 ON C1.POLICY=A.POLICY
    GROUP BY A.POLICY
)
SELECT POLYCY,BValues,CValues,BValues-CValues AS Final
FROM D
```

Comment: Since MS Acess SQL does not support WITH, what would be the best workaround without creating multiple intermediate queries?